# debootstrap --include not working as expected

Tags: debootstrap

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu OS image for use with `systemd-nspawn` by using `debootstrap` to create the OS image directory.  Lots of examples I've seen indicate that I should use the `--include` option, but I can't seem to get that to work.

```
debootstrap --include=systemd-container eoan ubuntu/
```

But when I run that (or seemingly any time I use the `--include` option), I get an error like the following:

```
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id F6ECB3762474EDA9D21B7022871920D1991BC93C)
I: Validating Packages 
I: Resolving dependencies of required packages...
I: Resolving dependencies of base packages...
I: Checking component main on http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu...
E: Couldn't find these debs: systemd-container
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that it was missing the "universe" repository.  Fixed by adding it:

```
debootstrap \
  --include=systemd-container \
  --components=main,restricted,universe,multiverse \
  eoan ubuntu/
```